# division using recursive subtraction

Tags: scheme, division, subtraction

I'm trying to get a function to work that divides two numbers, and returns their quotient.
***I need to use recursive subtraction to find the quotient.***

I don't really understand how to do this. I think I need a counter variable, which I increment by 1 each time I recurse the function. The problem is, I can only pass two arguments into this function:
 **(define (divide a b)**   so I'm not sure how to use the counter.

Can I get some psudeocode help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function result <- Divide ( a, b )
    counter = 0
    while a - b >= 0  do
        a = a-b
        counter = counter + 1
    EndWhile
    result = counter
End Function

Algoritm without_title
    write "which numbers: "
    read a b
    result = Divide(a, b)
    write "Result: ", result
EndAlgoritm
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: a translated pseudocode using pseint in spanish to english but the idea its the same

Answer (score 0):

The counter is implicit in the recursion:

```
(define (divide n d)
  (if (< n d)
      0
      (+ (divide (- n d) d) 1)))
```

Here *n* is the numerator and *d* is the denominator; we assume neither is negative. Here's an example:

```
> (divide 27 4)
6
```

This won't work if *d* is 0; do you see why?

Thinking recursively can be difficult when you first start. But if you keep plugging away at it, you will eventually learn to think recursively, and then you will wonder why you ever thought it was difficult.

Comment: Hey, that makes a lot of sense now! I see how the counter works in your code. Thanks a bunch. :)